# How React is able to access the variable before initialization?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
function app() {
  console.log(myVariable);
}
app();
const myVariable = "hello world";
```

I understand that the above code snippet  produces an error because I am try to access a const variable before initializing it but the code below doesn't give me any error even though I am trying to access `myVariable` before initialization. why is it so? How am I able to access `myVariable` even before initializing it ?

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {console.log(myVariable)}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

root.render(
    <App />
);

const myVariable = "hello world";
```

Answer (score 6):

`root.render` does not call the component passed to it synchronously. Quick demo:

```js
const App = () => {
    console.log('App running');
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);

console.log('Last line of the script');
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

If `root.render` *did* call it synchronously, like you're doing with the first snippet, an error would indeed be thrown.

A more analogous version of the first snippet, given what React's doing, would be

```js
function app() {
  console.log(myVariable);
}
setTimeout(app);
const myVariable = "hello world";
```

Comment: Any link or resource where I can read about it in detail?